# How can a Chain code be invariant to scale?

Tags: image-processing

If we normalize a Chain code by the first difference and shift it to the lowest value, making it invariant to a starting point and rotation, does it make it invariant to scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scale the object by 2x, you end up with ~2x the number of boundary pixels, hence its chain code will have ~2x the length. Thus no, the chain code is not invariant to scale.

However, you can derive boundary representations that are invariant to scale. For example using a [Fourier descriptor](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/fd/node1.html), which can be made rotation and scale invariant by an appropriate transformation.

Comment: Isn't the first difference measure only distance? and not number or pixels?

Comment: @gbox: Sure, if your object is a rectangle that is aligned with the axes, then the first difference will be the same four values no matter what the size is. But if you rotate the rectangle a bit, this is no longer the case. And in general, objects are more complex than a rectangle, the number of elements in the chain code, and the number of elements in the first difference will both change when you rescale the image -- and also if you do a sub-pixel translation, yielding a different discretization of the object. The same is true for rotation. Chain codes don't do well with invariants...

Comment: I also thought about it as, if we have a line of 2 pixel and of 4 pixel, as you said the length of the chain code, even the difference will be different